# php double if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm new to learning how to program. And I'm wondering what the best way is to handle the problem where you got a double if statement, with both having the same Else result.

Take for instance the following double if statement.

```
if (isset($x)) {
    $y = doSomething($x);
    if ($y == "something") {
        do result A;
    }
    else {
        do result B;
    }
}
else {
    do result B;
}
```

It doesn't seem like a smart idea to write result B multiple times.
Now what are the different ways to prevent having to write result B multiple times?

One can try making 1 combined if statement, but this doesn't seem always possible (for instance when checking with isset() if a variable exists).

```
if (isset($x) && $y) { etc. }
```

What other options are there?

PS. I'm also open for other suggestions to help improve my code, like how to write if(isset($x)) in a nicer way.

Comment: The question is not clear. For this particular case - it's easy and you have almost done that right. "in a nicer way" --- isn't it nice already? But it's strange to check if a variable exists at first place.

Comment: @zerkms "what are the different ways to prevent having to write result B multiple times?"

Comment: @Paul it's vague. "Write it once" --- does it count as an answer.

Comment: @Paul put it in a function and call it till your heart's content

Comment: `if (isset($x) && "something" === $y = doSomething($x)) { /*do A;*/ } else {  /*do B;*/ }`

Comment: This can depend on a lot of things outside the context of this example.  Is `doSomething()` a particularly heavy operation?  Does `do result ...` perform any kind of control flow (such as a `return`)?  Does a real-world example get complicated enough that the two conditionals represent two different levels of abstraction entirely?  Perhaps if you have a less contrived example which demonstrates the problem that might help, because this theoretical example isn't really clear.

Comment: @Leggendario one word: (operator) precedence

Comment: @developerwjk it doesn't seem like a good idea to have the same code be present two times, especially if result B gets large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (isset($x) && doSomething($x) == "something") {
    do result A;
}
else {
    do result B;
}
```

or

```
$successful = false;
if (isset($x)) {
    $y = doSomething($x);
    if ($y == "something") {
        $successful = true;
    }
}

if ($successful) {
    do result A;
} else {
    do result B;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($x) && doSomething($x) == 'something') {
    // do result A;
}
else {
    // do result B;
}
```

Important: `doSomething($x)` will only be calculated if `isset($x)` evaluates to true. Otherwise, checking the condition is aborted directly and the else-branch will be executed. So you don't have to worry about `doSomething($x)` giving any side effects if `$x` isn't set.

I'm not sure if this is documented behaviour, but it can be checked with this:

```
<?php
function checkSomething() {
    echo "Look, I'm checking something!\n";
    return true;
}

if (1 == 0 && checkSomething()) {
    echo "if\n";
} else {
    echo "else\n";
}
```

The output:

```
else
```

If `checkSomething()` would've been checked, it would have outputted `if` and also the `echo` in `checkSomething()`.

Comment: Removed my upvote after you added that ugly example with `global`.

Comment: @zerkms yep, it's ugly, you're right. I'll make it an echo :)

Comment: I actually liked your first suggestion with setting a $success variable.
After the edit of the post it just seems more complicated.

Comment: @Paul it's a side effect and a sign of unclean code, globals should be avoided as much as possible. Of course, echo is itself also a side effect, but it's different.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the ternary operator to set `$y`.

```
$y = (isset($x)) ? doSomething($x) : "some_other_value";
if ($y == "something") 
{
  do result A;
}
else 
{
   do result B;
}
```

If `$x` isset then it puts the value returned by `doSomething($x)` in `$y`, otherwise some other value you specify. Then you do your if-statement once on the value of `$y`.

Comment: It does not look similar to what OP has in their example. And it does not make much sense actually. If you just wanted to have a chance to use conditional operator, then you didn't succeed in it :-)

Comment: @zerkms, I'm assuming the OP actually wants the value in `$y` for something (perhaps in `do result a`) and the example was simplified.  If that's the case then if he does `if (isset($x) && doSomething($x) == "something")` another call to `doSomething($x)` would be needed to get that value again. The check against 'something' I figured was pseudo-code.

Comment: 1. your assumption is based on nothing 2. What is the point to set `$y` value to some hard coded value that will never match another hard coded value in the `if`? So I personally don't see any reason to use a conditional operator here (since it's semantically wrong here and only makes things more tangled)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help all.

I found the following to be the easiest and most clear way to solve this. Now result B is only written once instead of multiple times. Especially if result B gets long, this keeps it easy to read.

```
$failure = false;

if (isset($x)) {
    $y = doSomething($x);
    if ($y == "something") {
        do result A;
    } else {
        $failure = true;
    }
} else {
   $failure = true;
}

if ($failure == true) {
    do result B;
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way, I would have initially set $failure to true, and set it to false just before "do result A;" instead of having the duplicate code of setting it to true on 2 elses